# Dual monitor problem Kali

Tags: kali-linux, nvidia, intel

I am having some problems with dual monitors. It works on Ubuntu but couldn't get it work on Kali. I have an Intel Graphics Card (VGA connected) and another VGA to NVIDIA GT730. At first the nvidia didn't work, so only the monitor that is connected to Intel has worked. Somehow then, I managed to install the drivers. I broke the kernel 3 times while Im trying to install Nvidia drivers before.
Now the monitor connected to NVIDIA card works fine, but the other screen remains black but I am able to move my mouse on that screen too (however, the cursor icon is a cross sign). I cannot see more than 1 screen on Displays Settings too. Here is my xorg.conf file (I am sure that the BusIDs are correct, I verified them from lspci)

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig# nvidia-xconfig:  version 331.113  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-03)  Mon Dec  1 21:15:34 PST 2014


# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 331.20  (buildd@roseapple)  Mon Feb  3 15:07:22 UTC 2014


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" LeftOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection


Section "Files"
EndSection


Section "InputDevice"


    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection


Section "InputDevice"


    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection


Section "Monitor"


    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "LG"
    ModelName      "LG FULL HD"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 94.0
    VertRefresh     48.0 - 85.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection


Section "Monitor"


    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "LG"
    ModelName      "LG FULL HD"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 94.0
    VertRefresh     48.0 - 85.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection


Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 730"
    BusID          "PCI:01:00:0"
EndSection


Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "intel"
    VendorName     "Integrated adapter"
    BoardName      "Intel"
    BusID          "PCI:00:02:0"
EndSection


Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select +1600+0, DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection


Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: Not duplicate at all. Please read the posts before you suggest anything.

Comment: @GAD3R I don't think it's duplicate. Answer of the question you linked is a general answer for the beginners. This is a specific issue that op is having right now.

Comment: I agree that the OP asked a legitimate question.  We shouldn't be closing questions only because they're about Kali.

Comment: Stupid question but are you sure the cable of the second screen is properly plug ?

Comment: Just a free advise : If it's working in ubuntu, you should stick to that and add whatever kali tools you want to add by using repositories or maybe just clone from github what you want.

Comment: @Kiwy Yes, I unplugged and plugged it back to make sure. I can see the mouse moving on the second screen, but no windows or anything.

Answer (score 1):

A mouse pointer rendering as an X is indicative of an X display screen that is not running any window manager. You may even find that you can fire up a primitive clock (for example) or terminal with:

```
xclock -display :1
lxterm -display :1    # If no "lxterm" try "xterm"
```

In order to have this screen subsumed into your single logical X display you need to enable Xinerama. You have that listed in your configuration but disabled. Change the 0 to a 1 and it should all light up for you on the next graphical restart:

```
Option "Xinerama" "1"
```

Ideally you'd manage this from the Nvidia `nvidia-settings` program, but if you've struggled to install the Nvidia graphics driver this may not (yet) be installed.

Comment: The second screen is not connected to the graphic card its connected to onboard video card (Intel Graphics). Unfortunately, with the given commands above i could only fire up a clock on the right screen, the blank screen is still blank.

Comment: Setting xinerama 1 makes my only working monitor go away, i ended up with ACPI error on the non-working screen.

Comment: @phoeNix do you have the `nvidia-settings` app installed? If not can you install it? That would be best.

Comment: I have it, but cannot see the second screen on that app.

Comment: If you remove the `xorg.conf` entirely, you get just one screen? From there, can you use `nvidia-settings` to add the second?